# Boost::Asio - async_wait in async_accept handler crashes application

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am currently trying to create a server application using Boost::Asio that does two simple things:

1. Accept a client's incoming connection
2. Once the client has been accepted, start a `boost::asio::deadline_timer` which repeats itself

The following code shows my current attempt:

```
#define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Mswsock.h>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;

void timerHandler(const boost::system::error_code& errorCode, deadline_timer* timer) {
    timer->expires_at(timer->expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
    timer->async_wait(boost::bind(timerHandler, _1, timer));
}

void acceptHandler(const boost::system::error_code &errorCode, io_service *ioService) {
    deadline_timer timer(*ioService, boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
    timer.async_wait(boost::bind(timerHandler, _1, &timer));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    io_service ioService;
    tcp::socket socket(ioService);
    tcp::acceptor acceptor{ ioService, tcp::endpoint{ tcp::v4(), 12345 } };
    acceptor.listen();
    acceptor.async_accept(socket, boost::bind(acceptHandler, _1, &ioService));
    ioService.run();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Problem**:

The timer somehow does not work as expected in the `acceptHandler`. Somehow it gets cancelled twice, triggers an error on top of that and eventually crashes the entire application.

**Handler Tracking Output**:

```
@asio|1460922050.075890|0*1|socket@000000000015FAD0.async_accept
@asio|1460922051.153952|>1|ec=system:0 
@asio|1460922051.153952|1*2|deadline_timer@000000000015F608.async_wait 
@asio|1460922051.153952|1|deadline_timer@000000000015F608.cancel 
@asio|1460922051.153952|<1| 
@asio|1460922051.153952|>2|ec=system:995 
@asio|1460922051.153952|2|deadline_timer@000000000015F608.cancel
```

**Questions**:

1. What causes the `acceptHandler` to cancel the deadline_timer in line 4 of the Handler Tracking output?
2. What casues the error 995 in line 6 of the Handler Tracking output? Error message is: *The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request*
3. What causes the timerHandler to cancel the deadline_timer in line 7 of the Handler Tracking output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`timer` is allocated on the stack in the `acceptHandler` and is therefore not valid by the time `timerHandler` is called. You need to allocate the timer dynamically.

Also, you should check for error codes in both handlers. This is especially important when you want to end the program and `cancel` the timer.

Comment: What a stupid mistake. Thank you. I left the error-checks out for the simplicity of the snippet here. I usually work with switch-cases in all handlers.